# Published workbook on Tableau Server takes long time to edit and save

Tags: tableau-api

I am using **Tableau Desktop 10.0** and **Tableau Server 10.0**. 
I have published my workbook on Tableau Server. After that I am trying to make copy of my workbook which consists of **30+ sheets**. When I am trying to save my workbook by other name (using Save as option) it is taking **3-5 minutes** which is quite long. I am trying to figure out why is this happening? I have used quick filters on every sheet. Is because of this the process slows down? 
Please help me to figure it out.

Thank you.

Comment: How large is the workbook file? Do you have a lot of embedded images or parameters (All parameter values are stored in the workbook, so if you have a bunch of different parameters, that will increase the size)? The larger the workbook, the longer it will take to transfer across the network (and, depending on your network configuration, it could be a slow connection).

Comment: Thanks Aron for the reply. Size of my workbook is 4000 KB. I thought this is happening because of more number of sheets and the **quick filters** that I am using on my sheets. But in our case adding Quick filters in necessity.  I am thinking of splitting these sheets across 2 different workbooks. So that it could solve my problem